# How can I search PDF?

Tags: c++, linux, search, pdf

Im doing a small project in C++ in LINUX PLATFORM.i need to search 10 or more PDF files and find required data.how can i do so?.
i will make my question more clear with following eg

Suppose i have ten text books all about c++ and i need info about the topic array. How i can search the pdf and find data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext)

If you actually want to write code to do then you'll probably have to learn of to navigate the internals of a PDF file. There have been some answers on how to do that for example one pointing to this article which on the 2nd page has the code in C for a basic PDF parser
[xtractpro](http://xtractpro.com/articles/PDF-File-Parser.aspx)